# Можно ли посчитать конкретные значения String в массиве?

Tags: java, массивы, switch

Надо провести выборы среди элементов массива. Каждый элемент отдает свой голос за конкретное имя кандидата. Узнал, что оператор switch начал принимать String и решил поэкспериментировать, но выходит ерунда. Можно ли что-то исправить или подсчет возможен только для интовых значений?

```
public class B {
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private static String name;

    B(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numb = 0;
        int count = 0;

        B[] b = {new B("Mike"),
                new B("John"),
                new B("Mike"),
                new B("Mike"),
                new B("John")};

        for (B abc : b){
            switch (abc.name) {
                case "John":
                    numb++;
                    break;
                case "Mike":
                    count++;
                    break;
            }
        }
        if (count < numb){
            System.out.println("Mike");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("John");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: добавьте метку для указания языка

Answer (score 3):

Ваш код с `switch` верный.
Ошибка у вас в том, что в классе `B` поле `name` имеет модификатор `static`, а это означает что при каждом вызове конструктора `B` это поле перезаписывается.
Следует убрать `static` для `name`, то есть написать так:

```
private String name;
```

и всё станет хорошо

Comment: да у него ссылки проверяются!!!! стринг нельзя в switch впихивать!

Comment: @БорисовМакс, да ну. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html

Comment: О, спасибо. То что надо. Мне раньше IntelijIdea советовал впихнуть static, а потом я забыл об этом.

Answer (score 0):

А зачем здесь static? Статическая переменная создается в единственном экземпляре на все классы, и она просто перезаписывается, когда создается новый экземпляр класса B.
И вообще, зачем создавать класс для одной стринговой переменной, сделайте массив стрингов и работайте со  switch

Comment: Допустим будет массив стрингов, switch сможет отличить одинаковые значания? И можно ли будет потом их посчитать?

Comment: Да, есть пул стрингов. Но классы однозначно нет

Comment: @savimar, `switch` для строк работает с 7 версии джавы, я под своим ответом привел ссылку на документацию, там явно сказано что строки внутри `switch` строки сравниваются с помощью `equals`

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class B {

        private String name;

        public B (String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int numb = 0;
            int count = 0;

            B[] b = {new B("Mike"),
                    new B("John"),
                    new B("Mike"),
                    new B("Mike"),
                    new B("John")};

            for (B abc : b){
                switch (abc.name) {
                    case "John":
                        numb++;
                        break;
                    case "Mike":
                        count++;
                        break;
                }
            }

            if (count < numb){
                System.out.println("Mike");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("John");
            }
        }
    }

Пробуйте так и будет Вам счастье.
```